# How do I screen out NaNs when comparing floats in Ruby?

Tags: ruby, numbers, ruby-on-rails-5, nan

I'm using Rails 5 wiht Ruby 2.4.  How do I determine if a variable is a number?  I thought is_a?(Numeric) was the way to go, but apparently not with me.  I have this code

```
      puts "guesses arr: #{guesses_arr}"
      guesses_arr.map!{|str| str.is_a?(Numeric) && str == guesses_arr.max ? str : 0}
```

which dies with

```
guesses arr: [NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN]
ArgumentError: comparison of Float with NaN failed
    from /Users/davea/Documents/workspace/myproject/app/services/text_table_to_race_time_converter_service.rb:2121:in `max'
    from /Users/davea/Documents/workspace/myproject/app/services/text_table_to_race_time_converter_service.rb:2121:in `block (2 levels) in guess_headers_from_data_cols'
    from /Users/davea/Documents/workspace/myproject/app/services/text_table_to_race_time_converter_service.rb:2121:in `map!'
```

I'm unable to reproduce this in a console because I can't seem to produce an array with all those "NaN" values.  The point is, how do I make sure those don't get compared in my loop?

Comment: What would be an example of a typical `guesses_arr`?

Comment: I printed it out with "puts" (line right before the error message).  How else shoudl I get the values?

Comment: guesses_arr.first.class what is the output

Comment: How is `guesses_arr` generated? Having a few NaN to screen out could be fine, but having the whole array consisting of only NaNs indicate some other problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can produce an array of `NaN` values in the console like so:

```
[ 0.0 / 0.0 ] * 3
# => [NaN, NaN, NaN]
```

It's not entirely clear what your code is doing, but it might be worth noting that it's the `max` which is throwing the exception, and not the equality test. Incidentally, if you are trying to compare each array value against the maximum value - you might want to `max` outside of the `map`, to avoid having to evaluate it multiple times.

Building on top the other answer here on rejecting `NaN`s, you can put it all together to get something like:

```
# set up dummy data - 2 values and 3 NaNs
guesses_arr = [ 0.0 / 0.0 ] * 3 + [ 2.0, 3.0 ]
puts "guesses arr: #{guesses_arr}"
# => [NaN, NaN, NaN, 2.0, 3.0]

# remove NaNs in place
guesses_arr.reject!(&:nan?)
maximum = guesses_arr.max
guesses_arr.map!{|str| str.is_a?(Numeric) && str == maximum ? str : 0}
# => [ 0, 3.0 ]
```

---

Edit: if you have integers mixed up in the array, try converting them into floats first:

```
# set up dummy data - including floats and integers
guesses_arr = [ 0.0 / 0.0 ] * 3 + [ 2.0, 3.0, 0 ]
guesses_arr.map!(&:to_f).reject!(&:nan?)
# => [ 2.0, 3.0, 0.0 ]
```

Comment: Unfortunately I'm getting an "(NoMethodError) undefined method `nan?' for 0:Integer" error when I apply this to my code.

Comment: @Dave that means that you're mixing integers and floats in the array. You might have to include more detail on how the array is generated

Comment: Can you make the code work where "str" is anything -- making no pre-conditions about the type of number of even if it is a number?

Comment: After the "reject" you could "map" and either to_i or to_f everything (sorry about formatting - typing on phone). If you need something more specific, can you elaborate what logic you're trying to achieve?

Comment: Oh my bad, what I should have said is that the error I alluded to above is happening on the ".reject" line.

Comment: @Dave: see the edit above - you can convert all the elements to floats first, and then do the `reject!`

Comment: You could also test if the elements respond to :nan? before calling it: `guesses_arr.reject {|str| str.respond_to?(:nan?) && str.nan?}` That way you don't have to cast them to floats

Answer (score 0):

You can get `NaN` by calling `Float::NAN`:

```
[7] pry(main)> Float::NAN
=> NaN
[8] pry(main)> Float::NAN.nan?
=> true
```

If you just want to remove NaN:

`guesses_arr.reject! { |x| x.nan? }`

For example:

```
[4] pry(main)> [1.0, Float::NAN].reject(&:nan?)
=> [1.0]
```

Comment: Hey that didn't work.  Inserting "guesses_arr.reject! { |x| x == Float::NAN }" before my puts line still revels an array with a bunch of NaNs.

Comment: More concise: `guesses_arr.reject!(&:nan?)`

Comment: What? Does that run without error when you run that command in your pry console (Hint: the answer is no)

Comment: @Dave it does run with no error. What error are you getting?

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple of things that we can do. To answer the specific question.

```
arr = [1.0, Float::NAN, "1.0", "1"]
arr.map(&:to_f).reject(&:nan?)
```

would be a concise example around removing `NaN`

With a guess that you are trying to get a max value from inconsistent data, first we need to clean it up with a method like the following, which will convert a string or a integer to a float, or otherwise return `nil`.

```
def to_number(maybe_a_number)
  Float(maybe_a_number)
rescue ArgumentError
  nil
end
```

Assuming we have the above method

```
guesses_arr.map(&:to_number).max # or .min
```

That being said, the reason it's been hard to debug is the fact that you had a `.map!` that causes `guesses_arr` to be changing as you move over it.  (Generally we avoid use of the standard libraries bang methods as they object errors can be hard to debug.